# Error Class 'App\Product' not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've tried but this error showed up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wAqr.png)

```
public function render()

    {

        return view('livewire.home', [

            'products' => Product::take(1)->get()])->extends('layouts.app')->section('content');

    }

}
```

the `use\App\Product;` was used.

Comment: Maybe you should use *composer dump-autoload* to rediscover all the new laravel c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the location of your `Product` model.

If `app/Product.php` file exists, you can do like;

```php
use App\Product;
```

If `app/Models/Product.php` file exists, you can do like;

```php
use App\Models\Product;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify file name
2. Verify namespace
3. Verify path of file

laravel v8
ex: use App\Models\Product;